# Calculating the limit: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$ $\frac{\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})}{x^2}. $

Tags: limits

How do I calculate $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)}{x^2}\text{?}$$

I thought about using L'Hôpital's rule, applying on "$\frac00$," but then I thought about $\frac{\sin x}{x}$  which is inside the $\ln$: it's not constant as $x$ goes to $0$, then I thought that maybe this what caused that my calculating of the limit wasn't true.

Can someone clarify how we calculate the limit here?

Note: I'd like to see a solution using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Do you know the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: The limit of the full function is $-1/6$.  Try l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @mathmandan Shouldn't I check when x goes to 0 ?

Comment: I apologize.  I should have said: "Do you know the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: @mathmandan yeah, its 1. and I applied L'Hopital's rule but didn't work!

Comment: Well, it should have worked; I agree with David that the limit is $-1/6$, which can be reached using L'Hopital's rule.  You might have to add more details into your question, about what you tried and what you got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We want$$
L = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})}{x^2}
$$
Since the top approaches $\ln(1) = 0$ and the bottom also approaches $0$, we may use L'Hopital:

$$
L = \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{(\frac{x}{\sin x})(\frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2})}{2x}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{2x^2\sin x}
$$
Again the top and  bottom both approach $0$, so again we may use L'Hopital.

$$
L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x - x \sin x - \cos x}{4x \sin x + 2x^2 \cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin x}{4 \sin x + 2x \cos x}
$$

Again the top and bottom both approach $0$, so we may use L'Hopital for a third time:

$$
L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\cos x}{4 \cos x + 2\cos x - 2x\sin x} = -\frac{1}{6}.
$$

Comment: Thank you!! this is what I've been trying to understand !!

Answer (score 4):

As $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1-\dfrac{x^2}6+o(x^2) $, we have:
$$\frac{\ln\Bigl(\cfrac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr)}{x^2}=\frac{\ln\Bigl(1-\cfrac{x^2}6+o(x^2)\Bigr)}{x^2}=\frac{-\dfrac{x^2}6+o(x^2)}{x^2}=-\frac16+o(1),$$
which proves the limit is $\,-\dfrac16$.

Comment: thank you. see the note that I edited.

Comment: @Bernard Oh no! I didn't see your answer dude!

Comment: Am I a ‘dude’, mylord?

Comment: Sorry, mylord, sir!

Comment: @Community: I'm sorry, but your edit is wrong. You seem to have confused the `little-oh` and the `big-O` notations. I use the former.

Comment: (+1) I rolled back to your initial version, which was more appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use finite expansion for $sin x$ in the neighberhood of zero! Will lead you to $ln(1-x^2/6)$ ! Using finite expansion again on $ln(-x^2/6+1)$ will lead to $-x^2/6$! You can evaluate the limit then which will then lead to $-1/6$ i guess! Sorry for my bad language.

Answer (score 1):

Using taylor series you have

$$\color{#05f}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} + O(x^6)$$

and $$\ln \Bigg(\color{#05f}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\Bigg) = - \frac{x^2}{6} - O(x^4)$$

$$\lim _{x\to 0 } \frac{- \frac{x^2}{6} - O(x^4)}{x^2}= \lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{1}{6} - O(x^2) = \color{#f05}{-\frac{1}{6}}$$

**Edit:**

By L'hospital you have

$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}\frac{d}{dx} \ln \Bigg(\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigg) &= \frac{\color{#f05}{\cancel x}}{\sin x}\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^{\color{#f05}{\cancel{2}}}} = \cot x - \frac{1}{x} \\&\implies \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \ln \Bigg(\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigg) = \frac{1}{x^2} - \csc^2 x \color{#085}{\to -\frac{1}{3}} \end{align}$$

as $x \to 0$.

Then

$$\lim _{x\to 0 } \frac{\frac{1}{x^2} - \csc^2 x}{2}= {-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}} = \color{#f05}{-\frac{1}{6}}$$

Comment: thank you. can u show a way of using L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: There you have it.

Comment: but why the first one converges to $-1/3$ I just cant understand!

Comment: I've been trying to search for an email address of yours for mathematical consultation. (If u were able to help ofcourse) but couldn't find any.

Comment: Sure, It's on my profile.

Comment: I'm sure that I searched your profile very well. but found no E-Mail. do you mean the link where its written "website"? 

this one? 
http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?metodo=apresentar&id=K8137495T7

Comment: Enter a chat...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21125/discussion-between-firas-ali-abdel-ghani-and-aaron-maroja).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to compute
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln \left( \frac{\sin x%
}{x}\right) }{x^{2}}
\end{equation*}
only by making use of some basic limits: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u} &=&1 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}} &=&-\frac{1}{6} \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} &=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}
No l'Hospital's rule nor Taylor series are required. Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) &=&\frac{1}{x^{2}}\ln \frac{\sin x}{x} \\
&=&\frac{1}{x^{2}}\ln \left( 1+[\frac{\sin x}{x}-1]\right)  \\
&=&\frac{\left[ \frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right] }{x^{2}}\cdot \frac{\ln \left( 1+%
\left[ \frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right] \right) }{\left[ \frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right] }
\\
&=&\frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}}\cdot \frac{\ln (1+u(x))}{u(x)},\ with\ u(x)=\frac{%
\sin x}{x}-1
\end{eqnarray*}
since 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}u(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1)=1-1=0
\end{equation*}
then 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1+u(x))}{u(x)}=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{%
\ln (1+u)}{u}=1,
\end{equation*}
and therefore 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}}\cdot
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1+u(x))}{u(x)}=-\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1=-\frac{1}{%
6}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

In these cases using a Taylor Series approach usually gets you to the solution: The denominator will be expanded as:
$$\frac{-x^2}{6} + O(x^3)$$
 Thus dividing by $x^2$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ leaves you with $\frac{-1}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall l'Hospital's rule:  If the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ is undefined, and if the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ is also undefined, then calculate $f''(x)/g''(x)$.  In this case:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\log \left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right) = -1/3$

and

$\lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{\partial ^2x^2}{\partial x^2} = 2$,

so the limit of the full term is $-1/6$.

Comment: why undefined? $f(x)$/$g(x)$ its the limit of the type 0/0

Comment: $0/0$ is undefined.  If it isn't, please state the numerical value of it for me... what you would enter into your pocket calculator.

Comment: sorry. I misunderstood u. u used the rules twice because It wasn't defined.

Comment: @Stork:  The limit is defined since it equals the real value $\frac{-1}{6}$. You're right to say $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined, but the limit does not equal $\frac{0}{0}$. (hence his distinction of saying it is "of the type" $\frac{0}{0}$ rather than it "equals").

Comment: I think what you meant to say is if the (limit of $f(x)$)/(limit of $g(x)$) is undefined. But that's not quite the same thing. So it was a little confusing.