# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to { \infty } } (\frac{x}{x+2})^x$. Need for explanation.

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-verification, exponential-function

My question is about the procedure for this limit problem:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to  { \infty } } (\frac{x}{x+2})^x$$

My solution was like that:

$$(\frac{x}{x+2})^x=e^{x\ln\frac{x}{x+2}}
= e^u$$ with $\ u = x \ln(\frac{x}{x+2})$.

Then $$\lim\limits_{x \to  { \infty } } x\ln(\frac{x}{x+2})
=\lim\limits_{x \to  { \infty } }{\ln{x\over x+2}\over {1\over x}}$$

Applying L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to  { \infty } } -{{2\over x(x+2)}\over 
 {1\over x^2}} = \lim\limits_{x \to  { \infty } } -{2x\over x+2} = -2 $$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to  { \infty } } u = -2 $$

∴ $\lim\limits_{u \to  { \ -2 } } e^{u} = e^{-2} = {1\over e^{2}} $

However, according to my answer sheet, the correct answer is $e^{2}$. So, Please I need to know where's my mistake here.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer given to you is wrong; note that $\left(\frac{x}{x + 2}\right)^x$ is never larger than $1$, hence its limit cannot be larger than $1$.

Comment: Your mistake is in doubting your work and trusting the book to have no typos.  $e^{-2}$ is correct.

Comment: Another "mistake" (sadly extremely frequent on this site, like [here for instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147074)) is to overcomplicate things with the use of L'Hôpital's rule, instead of a mere derivative: $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\ln{x\over x+2}\over {\frac1x}}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-\ln(1+2y)}y=-2\ln'(1)=-2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct.

Also, we have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{x+2}\right)^{-\frac{x+2}{2}\cdot\frac{-2x}{x+2}}=e^{-2}.$$
I used the following property.

Let there is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}u(x)>0$, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}u(x)\neq1$ and there is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}v(x).$

Thus, since $e^x$ and $\ln$ are continuous functions, we obtain:
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}u^v=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{v\ln{u}}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}v\ln{u}}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}v\ln\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}u}=\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}u\right)^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}v}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct! Possibly easier proof
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^x
= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x+2}{x}\right)^x}
= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^x}
= \frac{1}{e^2} = e^{-2}
\end{align}