# Does series converge or diverge

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to figure out if the following series converges or diverges:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{n}{n+2})^{(n(n+1))}$

I tried using Cauchy's criterion:

$C_n = (\frac{n}{n+2})^{n+1}$

It seems to be less than 1 so I thought the series should converge but then realized that if I apply this method for example to these series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n})$, then it will also be less than one but the series diverges.

So what would be the correct approach here?

Comment: You are not applying [Cauchy's root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) properly. Look at $\lim C_n,$ not just at $C_n$ (For the harmonic series, the limit is $1^-$ so the criterion is inconclusive).

Comment: Possible suggestion: You've basically set up for the root test, now do long division on $\frac{n}{n+2}$ and a familiar limit should appear.

Comment: Or simply: $\frac1{C_n}\sim\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to { \infty } } (\frac{x}{x+2})^x$. Need for explanation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304258/evaluate-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fracxx2x-need-for-explanati) Together with the previous comment, it proves that $\lim C_n=e^{-2}<1.$